# Str object is not callable in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using Kivy in python trying to make the button "Save" run the "Save_number" function but I keep getting a "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"-error. Below is relevant code.

```
class DBScreen(Screen):
    def save_number(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        name = self.ids.save_name.text
        number = self.ids.save_number.text

        name = str(name).replace("(","").replace(")","").replace(",","").replace("'","")
        number = str(number).replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(",", "").replace("'", "")

        number = int(number)

        c.execute("INSERT INTO database VALUES (?,?)", (name, number))

        c.execute("SELECT * FROM database WHERE name=:name", {'name': name})

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    pass

    def save_process(self):
        self.save_name = self.ids.save_name.text
        self.save_number = self.ids.save_number.text
        if self.save_number == "" and self.save_name == "":
            self.disable_save()
        elif self.save_number != "" and self.save_name != "":
            self.enable_save()
    pass

    def disable_save(self):
        self.ids.save_button.disabled = True
    def enable_save(self):
        self.ids.save_button.disabled = False

    def load_number(self):
        global number_list
        global initial_length
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        c = conn.cursor()

        name = self.ids.load_name.text

        if self.ids.load_name.text == "":
            self.disable_submit()
        else:
            self.enable_submit()

        c.execute("SELECT * FROM database WHERE name=:name", {'name': name})

        name, number = c.fetchone()

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        number_list = []
        for i in number:
            number_list.append(int(i))
        initial_length = len(number_list)

    def load_process(self):
        self.load_text = self.ids.load_name.text
        print(self.load_text)
        if self.load_text == "":
            self.disable_load()
        else:
            self.enable_load()

    def disable_load(self):
        self.ids.load_button.disabled = True
    def enable_load(self):
        self.ids.load_button.disabled = False
```

Below is the relevant part of the Kivy file

```
<DBScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        padding: 20
        cols: 1
        rows: 10
        TextInput:
            id: save_name
            hint_text:'Name'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.705}
            size_hint: 0.95, 0.5
            multiline: False
            on_text: root.save_process()
        TextInput:
            id: save_number
            hint_text:'Number'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.705}
            size_hint: 0.95, 0.5
            multiline: False
            input_filter: 'int'
            on_text: root.save_process()
        Button:
            id: save_button
            text: 'Save'
            disabled: True
            on_press: root.save_number()
```

Error code

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\aronf\PycharmProjects\rtn\main.py", line 184, in <module>
     gui.run()
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 955, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 383, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 334, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 263, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1660, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1677, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1210, in on_touch_down
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 306, in on_touch_down
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1191, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\aronf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 55, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\aronf\PycharmProjects\rtn\gui.kv", line 124, in <module>
     on_press: root.save_number()
 TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You're overwriting the `save_number` method with this assignment: `self.save_number = self.ids.save_number.text`. Use a different name.

Comment: `self.save_number` is an attribute, not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function and a TextInput with the same name `number` and both of them are in `root` (`DBScreen`), so the interpreter doesn't understand which name you call and calls a TextInput, not a function as you expected. To fix the problem give a TextInput another name